# Ruby on Rails: not closing HTTP response (when "asian characters" are displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, jquery, post

everyone:

I have this nagging problem I cannot seem to fix. So, please, help me out!!!!

So, I have a page that renders a partial. The page gets renders correctly within a couple of seconds, however, Chrome still receives (by showing the "loading" icon") for some 30 more seconds and reports an error (failed to load resource) on Chrome Inspector. It seems like the response is not correctly closed. If I took out the line in the partial, that renders asian characters, it would work fine - meaning it would render the page and properly stops.

This problem gets worse, if the partial is gets rendered as part of an AJAX call via jQuery. It would not even get rendered then, because it fails to get a proper ending for the response.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Here is the HTTP header:

> Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source
>   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Connection:keep-alive Cookie:XXXXX Host:localhost:3000
>   Referer:https://localhost:3000/home User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
>   Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2 Response Headersview source
>   Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
>   Connection:Keep-Alive Content-Length:55118 Content-Type:text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 Date:Wed, 02 Nov 2011 23:07:52 GMT
>   Etag:"77d774b3b119012c5fabbd5c625a98a8" P3p:CP="CAO PSA OUR"
>   Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09) OpenSSL/0.9.8r
>   X-Runtime:1.070787 X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge

UPDATE:

I just installed Firefox/Firebug. They give more info than Chrome does. What a pleasant surprise!  Firebug confirmed my theory that somehow content-length got messed up.  So, if the rendered partial contains some asian characters, the content-length in the response header and  the actual response body size are different. If no asian characters are present, they are the same.  Has anybody seen this problem before?

Comment: What do the HTTP headers look like for the page?

Answer (score 1):

OK! We finally figured this out! YEAAAAH!!!

This was caused by WEBrick's inability to handle HTTPs correctly. Basically, WEBrick would not render pages correctly, which would causes a discrepancy between Content-Length in the response header and the actual body size. When this happens, the browser would wait for request to complete and throws an error (usually Failed to load resources error on Chrome) after 30 some seconds.

So, if you want to use HTTPs on your machine (localhost), make sure you use Thin as your server and nginx as a reverse proxy server. Even though it sounds complicated, it's not. Basically, Thin will serve up your pages just like how WEBrick would do.  If a HTTPS request comes in, say through port 443 or whatever port you set up for, nginx takes care of validating the request and forwards it to Thin, which then handles the rendering, etc.

I hope this posts would help someone..